# MERN: How to access build folder for Heroku deployment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku

How do I access the build folder in React from node for Heroku deployment? I'm getting errors and I'm almost 100% sure that I'm just not using the correct path.

My thinking was to use the standard path navigation `../`, but that appears to be an incorrect assumption.

**File Hierarchy:**

```
Project Folder 
|
|___Backend-Folder
|   |
|   |___App.js
|    
|___Frontend-Folder
    |
    |___build
```

**App.js (server):**

```
if (process.enn.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "../Frontend-Folder/build")));

  app.get("*", function (request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../Frontend-Folder/build", "index.html"));
  });
}
```

**Package.json build file:**

```
"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix ../Frontend-Folder && npm run build --prefix ../Frontend-Folder"
```

The [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=71wSzpLyW9k&t=390s) I've been working through have their server and build files in the same main folder so they don't need to back out. Any idea how to navigate to the correct pathway? I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is a typo in your code. It is supposed to be `process.env.NODE_ENV` and not `process.enn.NODE_ENV`

Also do this:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../Frontend-Folder/build")))

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "/../Frontend-Folder", "build", 
"index.html"))
})
}
```

Notice the "join" in the app.use and not resolve.

Your package.json build file should be:

```
"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix Frontend- 
Folder && npm run build --prefix Frontend-folder"
```